# get a button font from other applications

Tags: c#, api

hi
first sorry for my English
i try to get a word under mouse

now my problem how to get the font of button

i try to use

```
 IntPtr dc=    GetDC(button1.Handle);
 IntPtr last_font = SelectObject(dc, Font.ToHfont());
         Font fon = Font.FromHdc(dc);
```

but it gave me the font of the form

and some time gave me error
Only TrueType fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType font

after some trying with ch0kee answer

i get new result with this

```
 StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(1024);
 IntPtr fxx = GetTextFace(dc, 1024, Buff);
```

but Buff always return "system"

Comment: You want the text under the mouse pointer for your own application, or is it for any running application?

Comment: Do you really want to get the font, or is it the text that you want?

Comment: i want the font of button in other application so i use api

Comment: The code is bogus, you could *never* use button1.Handle *and* get a TrueType support exception.  Furthermore, a word is a word regardless what font was used to display it.  Voting to close.

Comment: please what do you mean "word is a word regardless what font was used to display it" i do not understand it, i need to know that font

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> However, for common DCs, GetDC assigns
>   default attributes to the DC each time
>   it is retrieved. For example, the
>   default font is System, which is a
>   bitmap font. Because of this, the
>   handle to a common DC returned by
>   GetDC does not tell you what font,
>   color, or brush was used when the
>   window was drawn. To determine the
>   font, call **GetTextFace**.

[GetDC Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd144871.aspx)

```
Font buttonFont = button1.Font;
```

thats all, don't get confused

```
MessageBox.Show(buttonFont.Name);
```

this prints me Microsoft Sans Serif default.

This is what you needed ?

Comment: I think the OP is asking for how to get the font of a button in another application's window.

Comment: i want the font of button in other application so i use api , i use the button1.Handle to test only, after i finished i will hook the mouse and keyboard to get the mouse position

Comment: okay, it wasn't clear, sorry. GetTextFace should give back the font name, at least in the msdn opinion

Comment: StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(200);
IntPtr fxx = GetTextFace(button1.Handle, Buff.Length,ref   Buff); 

buff  >> null

fxx >>0   please help me

Comment: the same result if withot ref StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(200);
            IntPtr fxx = GetTextFace(button1.Handle, Buff.Length,    Buff);

Comment: the same result with string             string space="";
            string str = space.PadLeft(200, ' ');
            IntPtr fxx = GetTextFace(button1.Handle,200, str);

Comment: the same result with    IntPtr dc = GetDC(button1.Handle);
  IntPtr fxx = GetTextFace(dc, Buff.Length, Buff);

the same result with

IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(button1.Handle);
 IntPtr fxx = GetTextFace(dc, Buff.Length, Buff);

Comment: the same result with

IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(button1.Handle);
 IntPtr fxx = GetTextFace(dc, Buff.Length, Buff);

Comment: i get new result with this             StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(5000);

            IntPtr fxx = GetTextFace(dc, 5000, Buff);

            but Buff always  return "system"

Answer (score 0):

You should sent WM_GETFONT (0x0031) message to a button. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632624(v=vs.85).aspx After processing that message handle of the font is returned.

Windows Forms uses pair message WM_SETFONT (0x0030) to set window font, you may see this via Reflector.NET in Control.OnFontChanged method.

Comment: [DllImport("User32.DLL")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
        IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);


    IntPtr fx = SendMessage(button1.Handle, 0x31, 0, 0);

Comment: You right, I just try it and have IntPtr.Zero returned. MSDN says result of the message processing can be null if control uses default system font, but I set custom font to button.

Comment: hi STO , can we solve that problem together i want to use google translate any ware like babylon. i do many steps except only this step