# problem using WM_GETFONT with standard flatstyle

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, fonts

I am trying to get the font of button in other applications.

When I try `WM_GETFONT`, it returns 0. This my code:

```
[DllImport("User32.DLL")] public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam); 

IntPtr fx = SendMessage(button1.Handle, 0x31, 0, 0);
```

I have known the cause of the problem, it due to FlatStyle property

See this  link

http://www.siao2.com/2008/09/26/8965526.aspx

How can I solve this problem?

I am using C# under Windows 7.

Comment: i edit my question form more explain , abut my rate : when i get i half a answer i select answer you can see my questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [get a button font from other applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566160/get-a-button-font-from-other-applications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're getting that value because the control you're checking uses the default system font.** 
If a custom font hasn't been explicitly specified, these are precisely the values that you should expect.

The `WM_GETFONT` message will always return 0 (or NULL) if the default system font is being used to draw the control's text. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632624.aspx):

> The return value is a handle to the font used by the control, or NULL if the control is using the system font.

Likewise for the `GetTextFace` function. In this case, the documentation for the related [`WM_SETFONT` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632642) provides some clarifying insight: If the `wParam` value is NULL, the control will use the default system font to draw its text.

Obviously you *haven't* changed the font, or at least Windows doesn't think you have. You mention that you're trying to get the font of *other* applications—how are you changing the font that is used to draw the text on controls in another application?

If you change your default system font, the behavior explained above still applies, regardless of whether or not what you see on your screen is different.

If you're sending the `WM_SETFONT` message, you might have forgotten to tell the control it should redraw itself. Again, pulling from the documentation linked to above:

> *lParam*
>
> > The low-order word of lParam specifies whether the control should
> >   be redrawn immediately upon setting
> >   the font. If this parameter is TRUE,
> >   the control redraws itself.

Comment: i edit my question for more details ,Of course I'm sure I changed the font type

Comment: How to solve this problem please help me i see that two  links but can't get the solution http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/108143-gettextmetrics-gettextface/
                           and the other link            
http://www.techreplies.com/development-resources-58/matching-custom-controls-font-dialog-boxs-377468/

Comment: @user545142: I don't understand what you're saying. I didn't post either of those two links. You can't get *what* solution? I just explained why what you're getting is the correct and expected value. No link in the world is going to change how those functions behave.

Comment: @Bahgat: Clearly my psychic debugger wasn't working very well last night. I wasn't able to predict what `FlatStyle` you had the button set to. The link you added to your question appears to explain the issue quite satisfactorily. Either change your `FlatStyle` to "System", or use the standard .NET methods to determine which font is set.

Comment: I'm not alone,many thanks  Cody Gray  I'm very happy for your replay, i try to make google translate any ware so i I want to get the word under the mouse I was able to do that with textbox and richtextbox  but not with other control

i tray to simulate that control  as richtextbox or textbox

by get size ,location and font of that control then call ScreenToClient
so the other control FlatStyle my be System or standard 
As you are a professional person and I am a newbie what do you think in my steps?? Is there a better way??and how to solve this problem ?