# can i get the font information from Graphics System.Drawing.Graphics in c#

Tags: c#

i get the Graphics from

Graphics g=  System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(button1.Handle);

can i get the font information from this Graphics

i was try to get a font by using 
GetTextFace api function but it return "system" it mean default font in OS

and i was try to use SendMessage(button1.Handle, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);  bu it return me 0 also it is mean  default font in OS

I have known the cause of the problem, it due to FlatStyle property

See this link

http://www.siao2.com/2008/09/26/8965526.aspx

thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're ultimately trying to accomplish. You've repeatedly asked questions about how to achieve an intermediate goal, but I think you're barking up the wrong tree. As far as Windows is concerned, that font is the standard system font—and that's about all you're going to get it to tell you. If you explained what all of this is intended to accomplish, we might be able to provide a solution that works.

Comment: i try to make google translate any ware so i I want to get the word under the mouse I was able to do that with textbox and richtextbox but not with other control i tray to simulate that control as richtextbox or textbox by get size ,location and font of that control then call ScreenToClient so the other control FlatStyle my be System or standard As you are a professional person and I am a newbie what do you think in my steps?? Is there a better way??and how to solve this problem ?

Comment: What went wrong with sending a `WM_GETTEXT` message to that control using the `SendMessage` function? Either way, I don't understand why you need the *font face* when you're simply trying to translate the text that control is *displaying*.

Comment: M_GETTEXT gaves me all text
so i need to get only the word under mouse
so i use EM_CHARFROMPOS 
after that i use EM_FINDWORDBREAK with WB_RIGHT
after that i use EM_FINDWORDBREAK with WB_LEFT

this way is very good when i used it with textbox or richbox

but not work with other control like button 

so i want to get the button size and location and font type and font size 
and mack a new richbox control with the button probertys 

then i can use the previous way to get the word under mouse

i know that my english is very bad but please help me

Answer (score 1):

What you're throwing together, as described in the latest comment, seems somewhat like a giant, messy hack. But I don't really know if I understand well enough to offer a better design.

Since you apparently seem to have some experience with the Windows API, you might take a look at Raymond Chen's blog post on [How to retrieve text under the cursor (mouse pointer)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/23/118893.aspx), as it sounds quite germane to what you're trying to accomplish. The code sample provided is not in C#, but it shouldn't be too difficult to follow the logic (specifically of `RecalcText`) to reimplement it using the same API calls in your preferred C#. Essentially, he walks you through taking advantage of [Microsoft Active Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697707) technology that is designed to expose information about the objects on the screen for reading devices and other similar technology, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel yourself.

Otherwise, continuing down the path that you've already begun, it sounds to me like you need to read up on the [`GetTextExtentPoint32` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938.aspx). Once you've sent the `WM_GETTEXT` message as I suggested above to get the text that is displayed on the control, you can get the position of the mouse relative to the control (using a combination of [`GetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390.aspx) and [`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558.aspx)), and check that against the width and height of the text string returned by `GetTextExtentPoint32`.

Finally, to answer the question you explicitly asked concerning how to determine which font is in use to draw a specified control, you need to recall the knowledge gleaned from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569723/problem-using-wm-getfont-with-standard-flatstyle/4569815#4569815) regarding the default system font. As you discovered, a control will either tell you which font it is using to draw its text, or it will tell you that it's using the default system font. The simple question then becomes, how do I know which font is the default system font?

That's a pretty straightforward question to answer, and the Windows API provides functionality to do just that. Specifically, you need to call the [`SystemParametersInfo` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947) and pass in the `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` flag. This will cause the function to fill a [`NONCLIENTMETRICS` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729175), which among other things, will tell you which font is in use as the default system font. Specifically, you'll be interested in the `lfMessageFont` member of the structure, which is a pointer to a [`LOGFONT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037) structure that defines the attributes of the font used on message boxes and controls.

Again, see [a post on Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/07/436435.aspx) explaining the history of `SYSTEM_FONT`, and his suggestion to use the `SystemParametersInfo` function to retrieve information about the actual font in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Graphics.GetHDC` and then use the `HDC` to get the font information throught a PInvoke call to native Win API.

**EDIT**

Look for `GetCurrentObject`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144869(VS.85).aspx
This function will let you get an `HFONT` from the `HDC`. Then you can use `Font.FromHfont` to get the .NET `Font` object.

If the `Graphics` object does have a font, you'll be able to get it through this API. Note that you need to release unmanaged resources that you would allocate (the `HDC`, and the `HFONT`).

Comment: what is the function that i can use to get the font from HDC without geting "system" ????

Comment: please read this link to know what is the problem              http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/09/26/8965526.aspx